# using the Onsen UI with nodejs for nomad

Tags: onsen-ui

Is onsen ui compatible with the nomad phonegap visual studio addition?  I tried to make a sample project but I was not seeing any results.  I believe its because you need nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Onsen UI works on nomad too. But Onsen UI employs Ajax (internally Angular's $http service) to load a page. Do you see any error about CORS errors on your console?